# How to parse a special parenthetical string in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following `line` string:

> (1,2,3); (3,4,5);(6,7,8); (9,10,11);

I want to extract the numbers 1, 2 and 3 from the first tuple; 3, 4 and 5 from the second one, and so on.

What I've done so far is with this code I extract strings delimited by ";":

```
stringstream ss(line);
string tuple;
vector<string> tuples_vec;
while (getline(ss, tuple, ';'))
    tuples_vec.push_back(tuple);
```

OK, so I suppose I'll have the following in `tuples_vec`:

```
(1,2,3)
 (3,4,5)
(6,7,8)
 (9,10,11)
```

Now, how do I extract the numbers from them? Notice there may be a variable number of blanks.

I think an idea for this part might be to remove characters until the first '(' and backwards until the first ')'. Then, with "1,2,3" I think I could do a `while(getline(ss, number, ','))`, but I think there is a simpler way. Also, I don't know how to code this part (removing characters).

Thanks,

Comment: have you heard of `std::stoi`?

Comment: @DanielDaranas I've updated my question with my idea for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string str; // input data

std::stringstream ss;
int x, y, z;
char fake;

ss << str;
ss >> fake >> x >> fake >> y >> fake >> z >> fake;

x, y, z; // output data
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why `fake` is of type `char`? I see that it's consuming more than one character from the input, so for me it would be a `string` (the answer appears to work, but I want to know why).

Comment: We know a structure of string, it's "(number,number,number)". If we representing this for parsing, it will be "char(bracket) + int(x) + char(comma) + int(y) + char(comma) + int(z) + char(bracket)" (whitespaces are ignored in stream with default flags).

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not state a requirement of checking validity of input syntax, the simplest you can do is

- Replace every '(', ')' and ',' with space.
- Replace every ';' with newline (this is not absolutely necessary, but it's simple).
- Read one line at a time using e.g. `std::getline`, place it in an `istringstream`, then read one number at a time from the stream.

The way I think about this, is that with the code accepting simple lines of numbers you can try it out by typing at it, or the like. And also support other formats.

Good luck.

---

PS: this is *not* a job for a regular expression. ;-)

Comment: Though, a regular expression would make quick work of something this simple.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's start with a `Line` class:

```
class Line
{
    int a, b, c;
};
```

We need to overload the extractor so that a formatted string can be parsed:

```
template<class charT>
friend basic_istream<charT>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT>& is, Line& line)
{
    return is >> line.a >> line.b >> line.c;
}
```

But in order for the extraction to work the stream needs to "ignore" the characters surrounding the important data. We need to make the stream parse `'('`, `','`, `')'`, and `';'` as whitespace characters.

The stream uses table lookup for objects of type `char`. We can make our own table as well:

```
class line_parser : public std::ctype<char>
{
public:
    static mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(),
                                   classic_table() + table_size);
        int table[10] = {0x20, 0x0c, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x09,
                         0x0b, '(', ',', ')', ';'};
        //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        for (int i : table)
            v[i] |= space;

        return &v[0];
    }

    explicit line_parser(int refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(), false, refs) { }
};
```

This is a derived class facet. We can imbue this facet onto the stream like so:

```
stringstream ss(line);
ss.imbue(locale(ss.getloc(), new line_parser));
```

But to be honest, it is a bit tedious. Not only does the user have to imbue a new locale into the stream, but they also must reimbue the original locale if they want to use the previous formatting settings later on. In order to facilitate this, we have to find some means of encapsulating this functionality. We will create a manipulator that does this for us:

```
template<class Line>
class line_extractor
{
public:
    line_extractor(Line& other)
        : line(other)
    { }
private:
    Line& line;

    template<class charT>
    void do_input(basic_istream<charT>& is) const
    {
        // imbue the new locale
        locale loc = is.imbue(locale(is.getloc(), new line_parser));
        is >> line;
        is.imbue(loc); // imbue the original locale 
    }

    template<class charT>
    friend basic_istream<charT>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT>& is,
                                            const line_extractor& le)
    {
        le.do_input(is);
        return is;
    }
};
```

Then to cut down on code, return it from a function:

```
template<class Line>
line_extractor<Line> get_line(Line& l)
{
    return line_extractor<Line>(l);
}
```

Now we are done. The input can be done as simply as:

```
stringstream ss(line);
vector<Line> v;

for (Line line; ss >> get_line(line); )
{
    v.push_back(line);
}
```

You should also add methods for retrieving the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

**[Here is a demo.](http://ideone.com/U6OLAb)**

Comment: This seems a little overkill

Comment: @Tim It may for this simple predicament, but when you have a large and complex code base, it is imperative that your code is kept clear and structured. This code is conceptually that which is used for the standard IOStreams inserters/extractors.